# iptables: drop all but group

Tags: networking, permissions, iptables, groups

I have this rule, which is working to block all connections for this group:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner has-internet -j DROP
```

I want to modify it to block all connections besides this group, however. I'm doing this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner ! --gid-owner has-internet -j DROP
```

But it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need two rules for this.

First, a rule to accept traffic coming from that group.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner has-internet -j ACCEPT
```

Next, a rule to block all other traffic.

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -j DROP
```

(NOTE: If these are the ONLY rules in your `iptables`' `OUTPUT` table, just use `-A OUTPUT` instead of `-I OUTPUT #`, but do these in order.  You don't need to use `-I` unless you have other rules in the specified table and are trying to insert rules at a different point within the table other than the end.)

Note that this may also run into some other problems, such as for things with `root`, superuser, or other service accounts trying to reach out, and can introduce other problems with network connectivity on the system itself that isn't directly related to Internet access.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I did try this method, but I wasn't able to make it work : ( Even if I just do `sudo -g has-internet ping somerandomsite.com` it doesn't ping. If you have a minute, can you please get a look at this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/738915/linux-iptables-accept-group-not-working . Thanks!!!!